# how to display json output in my codeigniter view?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am working a smole project airport search using Rapidapi but
i can't display json data from API in my codeigniter view. i'm googling meany time but not perfect result. please help

here is my json output

```
HttpResponse Object
(
[code:HttpResponse:private] => 200
[raw_body:HttpResponse:private] => [{"airportId":"6f576bf7-090a-46e3-be70-6d8a55275e04","code":"YYZ","name":"Toronto, Ontario","location":{"longitude":-79.63083299999998,"latitude":43.677222},"cityId":"8f65ce90-aafb-42b4-8185-ae4f1b131889","city":"Toronto","countryCode":"CA","themes":[],"pointsOfSale":["CA"]}]
[body:HttpResponse:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [airportId] => 6f576bf7-090a-46e3-be70-6d8a55275e04
                [code] => YYZ
                [name] => Toronto, Ontario
                [location] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [longitude] => -79.630833
                        [latitude] => 43.677222
                    )

                [cityId] => 8f65ce90-aafb-42b4-8185-ae4f1b131889
                [city] => Toronto
                [countryCode] => CA
                [themes] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [pointsOfSale] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => CA
                    )

            )

    )


)
```

my Controller

```
public function AirportSearch_form(){

  $url="https://cometari-airportsfinder-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/airports/by-code?code=yyz";
  $response = $this->unirest->get($url, $headers = array("X-Mashape-Key" => "ced348bae5mshd648601c9de77cbp1e2dcejsn222973a7564d", "X-Mashape-Host" => "cometari-airportsfinder-v1.p.rapidapi.com"));

  //echo'<pre>';
  //print_r($response);
  //exit();
  $jdata=json_decode($response);
  $app_title=$this->SuperAdmin_model->AppDataShow();
  $data['title']=$app_title->app_title;
  $data['menu_col']='';
  $this->load->view('agent/header',$data);
  $this->load->view('flight/airport_search',$jdata);
  $this->load->view('agent/footer',$data);

}
```

Comment: `i can't display json data from API in my codeigniter view` - why not, what is the problem?  Where is your view code?

Answer (score 0):

you have both json and non-json versions retrieved. as the latter doesn't require decoding i suggest you use that.

it seems like you can do `$response->body[0]` to get the array.

and specific items via `$response->body[0]->name` .etc.

Comment: how i show Location..longitude & latitude  .. $response->body[0][latitude]->name, not working..

Comment: @NoorMohammadBabu try this $response->body[0]->location->longitude